# Asp.net core EF, define detail table with 2 master tables

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm Using VS2022. Asp.net Core 6 Web MVC.
With Entity Framework, what is the proper way to create the Model Classes for the following example:

I have a master users table (named Users), and a master Areas table (named Areas).
I want to have a details table that combine these 2 tables in a details table, that contains the authorizations for each user to access an Area.
For each user, the details table must have information that defines if the user has permission to access each one of the areas:

```
--USERS---
ID Name     
1  Tom
2  Jack
3  Smith

---AREAS----
ID Name
10  LOGISTICS
20  FINANCE

----------DETAILS------------
USERID  USERAREA IsAuthorized
1          10         FALSE
1          20         TRUE
2          10         TRUE
2          20         FALSE
3          10         TRUE
3          20         TRUE
```

I'm newbie with MVC, and I just can't get this to work.
Can some one help me, please?
Thank you, in advance.

( model classes for database migration )

```
    namespace App.Models
    {
        public class AppUsers
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int Username { get; set; }
            public string? Firstname { get; set; }
            public string? LastName { get; set; }

            public ICollection<AppUsersAuth>? AppUsersAuth {get; set;}
        }
    
        public class AppUsersAuth
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public int AreaId { get; set; }
            public bool IsAuthorized { get; set; }
    
            //To retrieve the Area name, that has to be available in 
            //AppUsersAuth ICollection at class AppUsers
            [ForeignKey("AreaId")]
            public virtual AppAreas? AppAreas { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class AppAreas
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string? Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
    
    // Usage in controller
    
    public IActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var auth = _db.AppUsers.Include(i => 
        i.AppUsersAuth).FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
    
        // or in List Format

        var listAuth= _db.AppUsers.Include(i => 
        i.AppUsersAuth).OrderBy(i=>i.Username).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you simply have a `User` model, an `Area` model, and a `Details` model which has a `User` property and an `Area` property?

Comment: Given the updated question... Why does `AppDetails` have a *singular* `int` for `UserId` but a *plural* `List<AppAreas>` for `Area`?  (Putting aside for a moment the *drastically* inconsistent use of singular and plural names, which is pretty much guaranteed to lead to confusion and bugs in the future.)  In the example data shown, each "details" record has **a** "user" and **an** "area".  Why is the code model different?  Additionally, in the data shown there is a field called `IsAuthorized`, but then in the model it's called `Authorization`.  Is there a reason for changing it?

Comment: Hi David. My mistake. As you mentioned the Authorization field should be IsAuthorized.

Comment: I will update the models in the question. I will appreciate your comments then.